# OpenTBS - pasting into Excel using PHP results in "numbers stored as text" - how to resolve?

Tags: php, excel, opentbs, tinybutstrong

In Excel, on row 1, from columns A to K I have text representing column header labels.

On row 2, from columns A to K I have the following:

- [a.auditHour;block=tbs:row]
- [a.instance]
- [a.dataFileUsedMB]
- [a.dataFileSizeMB]
- [a.logFileUsedMB]
- [a.logFileSizeMB]
- [a.dataFileUtilisationPercent]
- [a.logFileUtilisationPercent]
- [a.dataFileMinSizeMB]
- [a.dataFileMaxSizeMB]
- [a.logFileMinSizeMB]
- [a.logFileMaxSizeMB]

I'm wanting the first column to be a timestamp/datetime, the second to be text/string and the remainder to be decimal numbers.

I have explicitly set those data types for the numeric columns in my Excel template (by right-clicking the column headers > Format Cells... > Number tab > Number > 5 decimal places and use the 1000 separator).

In PHP I have the following:

```
$TBS->LoadTemplate($template, OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8);
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_SELECT_SHEET, $sheetName);
$TBS->MergeBlock('a', $rows);
try {
    // Save the result file
    $TBS->Show(OPENTBS_FILE, $savePath);
}
```

The code executes successfully and the resultant workbook contains data.

However, when the resultant file is opened, all those decimal columns show little green triangles which, when I hover over them, brings up the yellow triangle with an exclamation mark, and the error message -

> "Number Stored as Text"

[image]

I tried working around this issue by building another worksheet that attempts to convert those text values into numbers using Excel's `VALUE` function; viz, cell C2 on my "calculations" sheet contains:

```
=VALUE(Data!C2)
```

The result there is the error:

```
#VALUE!
```

If I use the button "Calculate Now" in the "Calculation" group of buttons in the Formulas menu, the formulas are not recalculated .. but if I click into that cell and press Enter, the cell calculates and shows the value from the `Data!` tab.

I'd much rather not have to produce a calculation worksheet to resolve this.

It looks like TinyButStrong is wiping out the data type settings I had defined for the cells into which it is pasting.

What can I do to ensure the pasted data retains the data types defined within the Excel template?

Excel version:

Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2304 Build 16.0.16327.20200) 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

They are special operators for fields in OpenTBS that enables you to turn the data in a cell to the desired type.

See https://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc#cells